# Unable to echo value from html <option> from while loop

Tags: php, html, mysql

i want to `echo` selected parent value. but i am getting `error- Notice`: `Undefined index`:
How can i `echo` selected parent value then? Whats wrong i am doing?

```
$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM menu");
    echo '<form action="" method="post">
      Menu name:<input type="text" name="mname"><br>
      <select>';
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($q)) {
        $menu_name = $row['menu_name'];

    echo '<option value="'.$menu_name.'">'.$menu_name.'</option>';
    }
    echo '</select><br>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add Menu">
    </form>';



    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        echo $mname = $_POST['mname'];
        echo $parent = $_POST[$menu_name];
    }
```

Comment: add name attribute to select tag.

Comment: Note: `mysql_query()` and `mysql_fetch_array()` are deprecated, please use `mysqli_query()` and `mysqli_fetch_array()` in the future

Comment: `$_POST[$menu_name]`? `$menu_name` is only ever going to contain the LAST item you fetched from the db. And since your `<select>` has no `name`, it'll never get submitted with the rest of the form anyways.

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not use the [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It’s so awful and dangerous that it was removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$_POST[$menu_name]` probably doesn't exist, because only two elements in your form have `name` attributes.  The text `input` and the submit `input`.

`option` elements aren't posted as part of the form, but rather the selected `option`'s *value* for the `select` element.  But your `select` element has no `name`, therefore no key to use in the key/value pair, so it isn't posted.

Give the element a `name`:

```
<select name="someName">
```

Then in the POST, you would be able to fetch the selected value just as you do for any other form element:

```
$_POST['someName']
```

Answer (score 1):

add name to the select box and get the value of select box by name.
Updated code:-

```
$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM menu");
echo '<form action="" method="post">
  Menu name:<input type="text" name="mname"><br>
  <select name="menu_name">';
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($q)) {
    $menu_name = $row['menu_name'];

echo '<option value="'.$menu_name.'">'.$menu_name.'</option>';
}
echo '</select><br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add Menu">
</form>';



if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    echo $mname = $_POST['mname'];
    echo $parent = $_POST['menu_name'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add name attribute to select tag.

```
echo '<form action="" method="post">
  Menu name:<input type="text" name="mname"><br>
  <select name="any_name">';
$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM menu");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($q)) {
    $menu_name = $row['menu_name'];
    echo '<option value="'.$menu_name.'">'.$menu_name.'</option>';
}
echo '</select><br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add Menu">
</form>';



if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    echo $mname = $_POST['mname'];
    echo $select_option_name = $_POST['any_name'];
}
```

Note: mysql_* functions are depricated, use mysqli_* functions